# How make a simple javascript option menu

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and I need some help with my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function iMenu() {
    var Choice = prompt("Type in a number for the corresponding option\nOption 1: Hello world 1\nOption 2: Hello World 2\nOption 3: Exit");
    if (choice == "1") {
        alert('Hello World 1');
    } else if (choice == "2") {
        alert('Hello World 2');
    } else {
        alert('Bye');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="iMenu();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

1. I need to why my alert boxes don't appear.
2. Can I use functions for the options?
3. Can I have a function within a function and how many times is this possible?
4. In VB6 'End' is used to exit. What is the JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: Case: `Choice != choice`

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: You used 'Choice' as variable name declaration, but used 'choice' in you if statement.

Comment: Thanks. Question 1 solved.

Comment: Any help with the other 3 questions?

Comment: What do you functions for options? Instead of alerting a message you fire a function?

Comment: I was using alerts to test the menu.

Comment: Fuction 1: Should be a Temperature converter

Comment: Function 2: Radioactivity calculater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: You alert boxes aren't appearing as Javascript is case sensitive. You set a variable `Choice` and then tried to reference it in your `if` and `else` statement as `choice`

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function iMenu() {
    var choice = prompt("Type in a number for the corresponding option\nOption 1: Hello world 1\nOption 2: Hello World 2\nOption 3: Exit");
    if (choice == "1") {
        alert('Hello World 1');
    } else if (choice == "2") {
        alert('Hello World 2');
    } else {
        alert('Bye');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="iMenu();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Q2: Functions for options.

So instead of having alerts `alert("Hello World 1");` you can replace that with a function call i.e `doSomething(variable);`

Q3: Javascript function within a function.

The answer is **yes**. A quick example of this is:

```
function a(x) {    // <-- function
  function b(y) { // <-- inner function
    return x + y; // <-- use variables from outer scope
  }
  return b;       // <-- you can even return a function.
}

a(3)(4); // <-- This will produce 7
```

Q4: Within a JavaScript function you could just call `return;`

```
function test(){
   alert('Hello 1');
   return;
   alert('Hello 2');
   alert('Hello 3');
   alert('Hello 4');
}
```

This function will only produce 1 alert message